# I want to move to another sheet rows that have no value in a specific column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am recording a macro to be used for .csv files in Google Sheets.  Each contact has all the information in his row. Some of the contacts don't have an email. 
I want to add to the macro a function that automatically cuts the rows that have no value in the "Email" column and paste them in the second sheet.

Right now I only managed to cut rows based on their numbers, but of course this only works with a specific dataset.

```
spreadsheet.getRange('42:57').activate();
spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('K42'));
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Without Email'), true);
spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
spreadsheet.getRange('\'With Email\'!42:57').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
};
```

Comment: Do you really need a macro?  Have you considered a Filter View?  Under Date -> Filter views you could create a filter view and filter on the column containing Email and all the blank cells would be together.  It doesn't change you original sheet and you can even input values in the filter view and will be added to the row of your original sheet.

Comment: I guess this might be the best alternative. I wanted to create a macro that also downloaded the two separate sheets, but I guess that this would give me the same results with just a few minutes more. 

Thanks! I think I will go forward with this method

Comment: Welcome. Are you saying that this snippet shown above actually works? What is `getRange('42:57')`? what does it mean? I've never seen that before.

Comment: It selects the rows between that range. The problem is that different sheets will have the rows I want to select (the ones with value in a specific column = 0) in different rows.